# GOES AROUND(road) the backside of a mountain

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

When someone is telling you this:

> There is a great twisty road that **goes around** the back side of the mountain.

Does the "goes around" mean:

- it is *encircling* the back side of the mountain
- OR there is a twisty road *along* the back side of the mountain.

Comment: Perrsonally I think that should be *the **back side** of the mountain* - to me, the one-word form primarily connotes ***buttocks [bum, arse]***.

Comment: *Back side* as two words agreed if *side* is retained. But I see no need for *side*.  *Back of the mountain* is adequate.

Comment: Thx for spotting the mistake for the ''backside''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a great twisty road that goes **around the back side** of the mountain.

The meaning of this is closest to "It is encircling the backside of the mountain."
Specifically, it has to at least go from one side to the other.

If you intend it to mean "There is a twisty road along the backside of the mountain.", then you could write:

> There is a great twisty road that goes around **on the back side** of the mountain.

where *on the backside* can refer to anything on the other side.

Comment: Just to confirm, ''along'' the back side is wrong?

Comment: In your example "There is a twisty road along the backside of the mountain.", *along* is a preposition. Check def. 1 and 2 for [*along*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/along) and see if it makes sense to you.